# Auto-refresh NAS list in FreeRADIUS?

Tags: ubuntu, radius

We're using [FreeRADIUS](http://freeradius.org/) to allow routers to our hotspot network:

> FreeRADIUS Version 2.1.12, for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Feb 24 2014 at 14:57:57

We filter routers by their `nasname` in a MySQL DB, though when the IP gets updated, the radius service needs to be restarted before the router gets a reply from the server.

Is there a option to configure radius to **always** query the database, instead of caching on start?

Comment: Have you looked through the radiusd.conf file? https://www.cru.fr/nomadisme-sans-fil/ressources/radiusd.conf